# What's the point of the glass cases?

Tags: the-talos-principle

Some of the sigils correspond to glass cases containing various items, which sink into the ground when completed. However, since activating a few of them, I haven't noticed any sort of change. What are they for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After activating one, you gain the ability to use that item in puzzles.  Not all items are in all puzzles, though - the signboard next to the puzzle-entrance tells you which items need to be unlocked to do that puzzle.

Comment: Makes sense. I went through everything in order so I never reached a point where I was unable to use them otherwise.